# Remove space of string and compare using RegEx

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
Name was changed from *** to %%%
```

while *** and %%% can be anything.

What I need to do is to make sure that *** and %%% are different. I also need to make sure that if *** equal `Yan n` and %%% is `Yann` they will be considered as similar (white spaces can occur before and/after the variable).

My current RegEx only detect the sentence itself:

```
^Name was changed from.*to.*$
```

How can I make sure that it doesn't take into account when *** and %%% are identical (excluding the whitespaces)?

FYI I use this regex in VBA/Excel macro

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^Name was changed from (.+?) to (?:(?!\1).)*$`  https://regex101.com/r/5lqfqC/1 Is what is captured between from and to a single word or can it contain spaces? If not, you could use `\S+` instead of `(.+?)`

Comment: So it's exactly the opposite... for `atesta` in your example, it should count it as different (a match) while `test` and `te s   t` should be the same and therefore shouldn't match

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that with a single regex. A way to go: Select the two names, remove the spaces from them then compare them programaticaly.

Comment: @Toto I think that the first comment is quite close to what I need. There is only the issue of the whitespaces so I'm still hoping it's possible... programatically doing this is very easy but I am using a regex formula and would like to stick to it for simplicity and clarity

Comment: @Thefourthbird What if I forget about the whitespaces within the strings and would need to count the `atesta` as a match in your example? This would be already 99% of what I need... I see in your example that I can put whitespaces before and after the names which is what I need

Comment: If you capture `test` I don't think you can compare it to `te st` because the word `test` which is captured as a whole  does not occur in `te st`.

Comment: @ncohen Do you mean like this? `^Name was changed from (.+?) to (?!\1).*$`  https://regex101.com/r/33KLeC/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird It's close to perfect... is it possible also to match when it's `test` and `testaaa`?

Comment: @ncohen Perhaps like `^Name was changed from (.+?) to (?!\s*\1\s*$).*$`  https://regex101.com/r/EWwkD6/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems based on the comments using a capturing group in combination with a negative lookahead and a backreference to the group would be sufficient to get the matches:

```
^Name was changed from (.+?) to (?!\s*\1\s*$).*$
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/EWwkD6/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `Name was changed from (.+?) to` Match starting text and capture in a group non greedy what is between *from* and *to*
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is not

  - `\s*\1\s*$` Match 0+ whitespace chars, backreference to group 1, 0+ whitespace chars and assert end of the string
- `)` Close lookahead
- `.*$` Match any char until the end of the string